# Combining images not working in device iOS

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I am trying to combine two images into one. This is the code I am using:

```
 UIImage* image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.tif"];  
    UIImage* image2    = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sign.tif"];  
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image1.size);      
    [image1 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, image1.size.width, image1.size.height)];  
    [image2 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, image2.size.width, image2.size.height)];  
    UIImage *combinedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    imageView1.image = combinedImage;
```

It works perfectly in the simulator but does not work on the device. I get a white screen. Can any one please help me with this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "but does not work on device"? What is the result you see? What is the result you expect? What is the result you see in the Simulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this function:

```
- (UIImage * ) mergeImage: (UIImage *) imageA
            withImage:  (UIImage *) imageB
             strength: (float) strength {

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake([imageA size].width,[imageA size].height), NO, 0.0); 

[imageA drawAtPoint: CGPointMake(0,0)];

[imageB drawAtPoint: CGPointMake(0,0) 
          blendMode: kCGBlendModeNormal // you can play with this
              alpha: strength]; // 0 - 1

UIImage *mergedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); 
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return mergedImage; 
 }
```

And call it like this:

```
UIImage* image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.tif"];  
UIImage* image2    = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sign.tif"]; 

UIImage *mergedImage =[self mergeImage:image1 withImage:image2 strength:1];
```

Comment: Nope it does nt work. I have the same issue works in simulator but not on device.

Comment: Check your file names again, the simulator is a forgiver when it comes to file names. check for capitalizations maybe?